# Descening order for the string [name]

Tags: java, arrays

help please on sorting string according to the top number/score (btw according to our instructor, we can't use "arrays.sort")

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{

public static void main(String[] args) {   

 
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] name = new String[10];
    int [] score = new int [10];     
    int temp = 0;    
        
    //Displaying elements of original array 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
    System.out.println("\nNumber " + (i+1));
    System.out.print("Input your name: ");
        name[i] = sc.next();
    System.out.print("Input your score: ");
        score[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }    
        
    //Sort the array in descending order    
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {     
        for (int j = i+1; j < score.length; j++) {     
           if(score[i] < score[j]) {    
               temp = score[i];    
               score[i] = score[j];    
               score[j] = temp;    
           }     
        }     
    }    
        
    System.out.println();    
        
    //Displaying elements of array after sorting    
    System.out.println("Elements of array sorted in descending order: ");    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {     
        System.out.println("the score of " + name[i] + " is " +score[i] + ". ");    
    }    
}
```

}

The example Input is like this

```
k1 96
k2 92
k3 94
k4 98
k5 91
k6 95
k7 90
k8 99
k9 93
k10 97
```

The desired output that I want is like this

```
k8 99
k4 98
k10 97
```

But what happens is:

```
k1 99
k2 98
k3 97
```

please help, would love a simple explanation. Thank you.

Comment: You only sort the `score` not the `name`, then you select the values at the same position in both arrays but those values are generally not connected to each other. Think about creating a class `Wrapper` which has both a `name` and a `score` attribute and have an array of `Wrapper` and then sort that. This way you will always have the `name` and the `score` closely associated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two arrays, one named `name`, and one named `score`.

You only sort `score`, while making no changes to `name`.

I would suggest either one of two solutions:

1. Keep names and scores in objects, and store these in one array, and sort that array based on scores.

or

2. Do the same index changes to `name` as you do to `score`.

I would suggest trying to implement number 1, as name and score are conceptually part of the same object, like "age" and "name" would be for an object representing a "person".

Hope this helps, good luck with your assignment :-)

Answer (score 0):

```java
//Sort the array in descending order    
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {     
        for (int j = i+1; j < score.length; j++) {     
           if(score[i] < score[j]) {    
               temp = score[i];    
               score[i] = score[j];    
               score[j] = temp;    
           }     
        }     
    }
```

Here, when you sort the arrays, you only swap `score` elements. To maintain the `name`/`score` pairing you should swap even name elements:

```java
//Sort the array in descending order    
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {     
        for (int j = i+1; j < score.length; j++) {     
           if(score[i] < score[j]) {    
               temp = score[i];    
               score[i] = score[j];    
               score[j] = temp;
               tmp = name[i]
               name[i] = name[j]
               name[j] = tmp
           }     
        }     
    }
```